# Power BI Server Override Credentials

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

We have a dashboard deployed on a Power BI Server On-premise. So no Azure AD solutions please.

We would like to display this dashboard on an Extranet Web Application that uses Forms Authentication for its users. We currently use iFrame or redirect URL access, since those are the only options.

We don't want the Users to login again to view reports since they have already logged in to the Application. They are currently being prompted.

How can we use a common credential(preferably AD account) to authenticate/authorize each dashboard view? We want to be able to change the credentials programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a custom authentication extension. You should be able to use the existing SSRS documentation, given that Power BI Report Server is essentially a direct superset of SSRS. If you want to use AD accounts, you'll have to establish a normal AD authentication flow in your application, as well as pass on a valid cookie over to the SSRS side of things. Microsoft has pretty extensive documentation, as well as samples on this:

Documentation on custom authentication:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/security-extension/authentication-in-reporting-services

Repository with samples:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample

Comment: Already Looked at that but unfortunately that does'nt allow you to pass in a credential from your application. The credential is fixed when the custom extension is deployed to the report server. We want to be able to pass in a security context.